# Which is the best way to go from La Guardia to Manhattan

Tags: public-transport, transportation, airport-transfer, new-york-city, lga

I want to know which way is the best in terms of money, comfort and speed to go from La Guardia airport to Manhattan(Time Square).

**Extra info:**

- I am going with 3 other people, so **we are 4** in total.
- Possible **luggage: 1 suitcase and 1 backpack each one**, another
  small suitcase could be added (just one, not another one per person).
- We should be arriving at 9 am

If your answer isn't valid to go back to La Guardia, please point it out.

Comment: The [Q70 bus](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/NewQ70LimitedStopService_brochure.htm) will connect you to the subway system with a free transfer: $2.75 per person all in.  I don't think you will beat that for price.

Comment: Thanks!, is it safe? Is it comfortable to go with all the luggage?

Comment: I haven't personally taken that particular route, and "safe" and "comfortable" will depend on your personal standards.  If it were me I would do it.

Comment: @Redithion depending on where in Manhattan you're going, you might get there directly with the M60 bus, or take the M60 bus and transfer to the N or Q subway line at the Astoria Boulevard station.  You can also take a taxi, though it might be a squeeze with all that luggage, and there are some shuttle bus services.  The buses are safe, and they are reasonably comfortable (by the standards of potentially crowded city transportation) if you are relatively able-bodied, or if you are lucky enough to get a seat.  With a 9 am arrival, you might just miss rush hour.

Comment: Yeah, I meant standard safety and standard comfort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option if you decide to take public transportation you should take [M60-SBS](http://bustime.mta.info/m/?q=M60-SBS) directly into Manhattan or you could stop at Astoria Blvd, and change for [N, Q](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tncur.pdf) subway trains, which will take about 10-15 minute ride to Manhattan's West Side conditions permitting.

The bus has low ramps for easier access with luggage.

You can take [Q70](http://bustime.mta.info/m/?q=Q70) bus to the [F Train](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tfcur.pdf) or an [E Train](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/pdf/tecur.pdf) but it will take longer and buses are less convenient when carrying luggage.

Comment: I read some reviews about [Q70](http://www.yelp.com/biz/q70-to-laguardia-new-york) and [M60](http://www.yelp.com/biz/m60-bus-to-laguardia-airport-astoria). According to that, I would prefer Q70.

Comment: Considering the ground transportation situation in LGA in general it's 6 on one side half dozen on the other. During busier times thr airport is next to impossible to get around now since lanes crisscross each other and multiple traffic lights holding up traffic. I always consider LGA as an airport of last resort, so Q70 being slightly better than M60 is a cold comfort for me.

Comment: Hoyt Ave is an obsolete name for the station.  The street that gave its name to the station was renamed at some point roughly a century ago.  I lived one block from that station for six years (much more recently), and I can assure you that you'll have much better luck if you call the station *Astoria Boulevard.*  Since the M60 travels along Astoria Boulevard, the name of the bus stop you want is *31st Street.*

Comment: @Redithion where is your destination in Manhattan? That is also a consideration in making the choice.

Comment: @phoog Ok.  Did that route once.  Won't do it again since I would much prefer Uber but during rush hour this seemed like a better idea.  Now I know I could probably walk fron Astoria faster.

Comment: @Karlson I walked it once when the bus passed me by in the wee hours, when the buses run every 30 minutes.  The bus is definitely faster than walking, barring exceptionally unfavorable circumstances, especially if you have cumbersome bags.  Taxi is faster, of course.

Comment: @phoog I caught a bus right away but it took 10 minites to get to the airport and 40 minutes to get to terminal B.  I hate LGA.

Comment: @phoog I will be near Carnegie Hall

Comment: @Redithion N/Q trains drop you off closest to the Carnegie Hall.

Comment: @phoog You're right the Train Stop is Astoria Blvd, Bus stop is Hoyt/31.

Comment: @Karlson Well what do you know? It turns out that the bit west of 31st Street is still called Hoyt Avenue. Still, the [bus schedule](http://web.mta.info/nyct/bus/schedule/manh/m060scur.pdf) calls the stop "31 St," noting the transfer to the N/Q at "Astoria Blvd." The official name of the N/Q station is "Astoria Blvd/Hoyt Ave," but, as I said, most people just call it Astoria Blvd. Using "Hoyt" risks confusion with Hoyt St. or Hoyt/Schermerhorn in Brooklyn  It's not likely, but it's possible. The main problem with using "Hoyt," however, is that most people won't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @phoog So just ask about the subway transfer. :)

Comment: @Karlson So does R subway right?

Comment: @Redithion Except it doesn't go to Hoyt.  Only if you take Q70

Comment: @Redithion R subway goes to the same 57th St/7th Ave station as N/Q.  If you take the Q70, it would be quicker for you to take the F train and walk from 6th Avenue (<5 minutes) because the F is an express train.  If you board the train near the rear (R or F), you will be closer to 57th St when you emerge from the station.

Comment: Cool, thank you all! I will explain this information to my group so we can vote what to do.

Comment: @redithion U can uee Google Maps to explain.

Comment: For sure, I've been using it and it's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Karlson's answer certainly wins out in terms of money...

but for comfort and speed, with four people, each carrying luggage, I'd say a Taxi will probably win out handily for comfort and speed. Going from LGA to Midtown Manhattan should cost about 30-40 bucks (total), including tip, depending on traffic, and the trip should take about 45 minutes. Arriving at 9AM, by the time you get your luggage curbside, you should miss the worst of rush-hour, hitting whichever bridge you take at 10 or so.

When you exit baggage claim at LGA, there should be a prominent taxi stand where you can simply hop in line, and will be paired off with a cab - there are minivan taxis in circulation that you should be able to request if the extra cargo capacity for your luggage is an issue - no price difference, but you might have to wait an extra few minutes.

(If you do need that larger taxi, going back to LGA might be a bit more difficult - getting a minivan cab from a street hail can be hit or miss. If your hotel has a porter at the door, they can easily hail one for you while you wait inside without issue though. If that's not an option, Uber/Lyft/Livery Services will all offer you a larger vehicle at a comparable price without much issue.)

Comment: Thanks, do you think the four of us could travel in the same taxi? Even with all the baggage?

Comment: it depends on the size of your luggage. Certainly you'd have no problem fitting into one of the vans that are availiable. (And you should have no trouble at all getting one of those at the airport.)